# Make text bold in vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make text bold in vim](https://superuser.com/questions/489249/make-text-bold-in-vim)

I am working on Ubuntu and using **vim** to make C files. I want to make the entire text in the editor **bold**. How can I do that without installing any plugin? I am not looking to make specific words bold. I am using a black background. Colors in bold would make the editor look really good.

Comment: Are you using vim in a terminal/console session - so you just want to use a bold font rather than a regular font in the console?  If so, what console application are you using?

Comment: @Paul: I am using bash. I do not want to make the text in the shell. I want it only for Vim. Can you help?

Comment: @ParthShah: vim running as a console application uses the fonts provided by the console / terminal. you can specify fonts within vim only when running in a gui-version.

Comment: @akira: Perfect! That's the answer I was looking for. Seems so obvious. Silly me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vim in the terminal and don't mind making the text bold for all your terminal windows, you can usually change the font (and font weight) in the terminal emulator. E.g. if you use gnome-terminal (the default), you can go Edit > Preferences, untick "Use the system fixed width font" and then click the font and choose the *bold* variant of the one you want from the list.

If you use a GUI Vim such as GVim, you can change the font: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font, and simply specify the bold variant, e.g. "Monospace Bold".

Comment: It does not look good in the terminal! It looks good only in vim. GVim is obviously a solution. Any other solution specifically for Vim?