# Make text bold in vim

Tags: vim

I am working on **Ubuntu** and using **vim** to make **C** files. I want to make the entire text in the editor **bold**. How can I do that without installing any plugin? I am not looking to make specific words bold. I am using a black background. Colors in bold would make the editor look really good.

Comment: are you running vim in a terminal or a gui version?

Comment: I believe you should configure the terminal, not vim. Hence 1) asking what terminal do you use? 2) seconding the request to move the question to superuser.

Comment: @Zyx: I use the bash terminal

Comment: @ParthShah No, bash is the shell and not a terminal. “Terminal” here is a short of “terminal emulator”: GUI application you use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer was given to me by one of the users @akira in one of the comments. I am just sharing it.. 
You can change the font only in GVim. Vim uses the fonts that you are using in the shell. So if you happen to be reading this and have the same requirement the best thing would be to change the settings of your shell such that it displays fonts in bold. I believe this is the best method.

Comment: Also, note that a font has different files for its styles, so just downloading "SomeFont.ttf" does not mean you download all styles, but most likely only "Regular". All desired font styles need to be installed separately.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `:match` command to apply a highlight to a given regular expression.
For gVim:

```
:highlight MyGroup gui=bold
:match MyGroup /./
```

For terminal:

```
:highlight MyGroup cterm=bold
:match MyGroup /./
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make **bold** some elements of **C** file. For example

```
:highlight Comment gui=bold
```

will make comments in **C** files **bold** for **GVim**. For console **Vim** it will be

```
:highlight Comment cterm=bold
```

Unfortunately, I do not know other way to make all text **bold** except for making it bold for each highlight group (`cComment`, `cNumber`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

For Gvim only: Change the font to bold using(Monospace in this example)

```
:set guifont=Monospace\ Bold\ 11
```

Put it in your `.gvimrc` if you want to do it every time.

Comment: Nothing changes. Can you plz tell me what can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your terminal emulator's settings to make your fonts **bold**.

On a `tty` console, run:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

and then adjust settings from there.

**Note:** You cannot do this in xterm.